# How can I create a re-usable CloudFormation template for my Lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, devops

can someone help me to create a reusable lambda function in reusable Cloudformationtemplate?

tried in different articles but couldn't find which allows us to use existing IAM, VPC, SG and etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You are more likely to get a helpful response from the community if you [show what you have tried so far](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is a very general Q, I agree with @fedonev.  It helps if you show us what you have done.  You may also want to check out the CDK.  It gives you the ability to write code in a language that you are familiar with, which in turn generates the template.  https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/